# RxJS retry to get data after logged in - if logged in try once

Tags: angular, rxjs5, ngrx

I have the following problem that I want to solve with RxJS (Angular 4)

- if not logged in request for data fails (403 forbidden)
- if the request fails with 403 I want to retry the request for the data when I'm logged in
- while I'm logged in I want to request data once when the user visits a view that requires the data

I have the following streams

```
const isLoggedIn$ = store.select('currentuser').filter(user => user.id)
const loadActions$ = storeActions$.filter(action => action.type == 'LOAD_DATA_REQUEST')
```

I have some code but it's not fulfilling all of the conditions above

```
loadActions$.take(1).subscribe(() => { http.get('/api/data') ... })
```

Works when I'm logged in and I am allowed to access the data but fails when I'm not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

First: you should not make a get-call inside of a subscriptions, that being said,
you could use [`retryWhen`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen) for this:

```
const isLoggedIn$ = store.select('currentuser').filter(user => user.id)
const loadActions$ = storeActions$.ofType('LOAD_DATA_REQUEST');

loadActions$
    .take(1)  // not sure if you need this, I just copied it from your code
    .switchMap(() => {
        return http.get('/api/data')
            .retryWhen(error => isLoggedIn$.take(1)); // optional: use the "error" parameter to check if the error is 403
    })
```